# Hide files that begin with a dot in Windows

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide dotfiles in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/236939/hide-dotfiles-in-windows)

Is there a way to have Windows automatically hide any file that begin with a dot the way it's done in Linux?

PS I have seen this [Hide dotfiles in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/236939/hide-dotfiles-in-Windows)

Comment: If you've seen that question, why did you ask it again?

Comment: it just just a command/batch file to run. which as to be run everytime

Comment: The accepted answer states "If you want this for a few directies, just set it to run once a day on that directories." [sic] so it covers what you are asking for. If you don't know how to set up automated tasks in Windows then that is a completely different question, and also answered here on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether there is a way to change the default behavior in Windows to automatically hide these files, the answer is no.