# Hiding files/folders which begin with a full stop (period)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows does not use the [dot-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) convention for hidden files. However, many Windows applications (mostly opensource/cross-platform) use files and folders with this convention. How can I make Windows Explorer automatically hide these dot-files?

Comment: One caveat is that Windows hidden files work differently than Linux/MacOS. This makes the files hidden to other tools too, as pointed out in some other answers. This can cause errors to happen in unexpected situations.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ATTRIB +H /s /d C:\.*` is the command to hide anything, directories included that start with a dot

This won't list the files (as stated below), but will hit every file it can access, and apply the Hidden attribute.

Once this is done, you can make sure that the Folder Options are set to hide hidden files. Click on **Start**, type `folder options` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click on the **View** tab, then choose *Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives* under **Files and Folders** \ **Hidden files and folders**. Hit **Apply**, then **OK** (or just **OK**).

Comment: only thing that sucks about this... it doesn't output anything. No way to verify which files it touched. =(

Comment: another thing that sucks, is that it you have to do it manually every time you get such files.

Comment: my `Users` folder is ever so grateful

Comment: Beware: on Windows files `CreateFile` calls with `CREATE_ALWAYS` but without explicitly specified `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` flag, operations will fail on hidden files. Some tools are aware about this, but with some (sorry, don't remember exactly what I had issues with) this happens silently and the only noticeable problem is that configs or logs are somehow not updated. Check e.g. here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215998/116546

Comment: This is causing error in my development process.
After doing this I am not able to properly use yarn
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\raksh\.yarnrc'

Comment: @RakshitArora Unfortunately, I don't know why that would be happening. What does Yarn's support team say about it?

Comment: I saw some issues already posted about it, here is the original one https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5261
So, I guess, using a third party File manager is best option for me. 
Anyways, if someone is facing same error, you can specifically unhide the .yarnrc in your home dir, or undo the command by ATTRIB -H /s /d C:\.*

Comment: What I want to know is why any Windows programs create dotfiles to begin with. Like if they wanted to be hidden, they should set the hidden flag. Otherwise why use the dot at all? Seems really weird

Answer (score 12):

Simple:

In Windows Explorer

1. Right click on the `.folder` you want to hide;
2. Click `properties`, then click on the `general` tab;
3. Click on `hidden`.

Done.

PS Only checked on Windows 7 Professional.
PPS I noticed your question asked for doing this automatically.  Clearly this won't cut it, but maybe readers find it useful.

Comment: way better solution to hide folders and files in user folder, you can always revert this, and also see the files if you need just by pressing together ctrl+h

Comment: Doesn't work on files in OneDrive mounts.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in C#, using System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.
Code would be something like this. Just compile it and place it in the Start Up folder. But this code doesnt hide already existing files. So run first the code from Luke, and than this code.
You need the System.IO and System.Security.Permissions

```
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = "C:\\";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
        while (true) ;
    }
    static void Check(string filename)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        if (name.StartsWith(".") && !File.GetAttributes(filename).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
        {
            File.SetAttributes(filename, File.GetAttributes(filename) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
        }
    }
    static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Check(e.FullPath);
    }
    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Check(e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows will hide files with the *hidden* or *system* flag. Or files may be hidden using ACL. Windows does not hide files based on filename.

To explicitly have Windows to hide files by filename, you'll need to explicitly create the feature.  Either a file system driver (it use to be common for viruses to have this "feature") or a shell extension hack will work in this case.

On a side note, you can fake the feature by turning off "view file extensions" under Folder Options, since, to Explorer,  a file that starts with a dot is a file with an extension, but no name.

Comment: Windows does not have an option to hide *all* file extensions. This is the only related option: `Folder Options` > `View` > `[ ] Hide extensions for known file types`.

Comment: Like I said, not a real feature.

Comment: Hiding extensions for known file types doesn't seem to actually hide such files though. I still see them listed in explorer, just with a blank name. It also doesn't appear to affect folders at all (eg. ".txt" is still displayed in full). Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this powershell function which I placed in my powershell profile file so that whenever I start a new powershell session, the function is readily available.

```
function hide-dots {
    param([string]$path=".")

    if ($path -eq ".") {
        $cwd = (Get-Location).Path.Substring((Get-Location).Path.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        echo "Searching for files in $($cwd) ..."
    }
    else {
        echo "Searching for files in $($path) ..."
    }

    $Activity = "Hidding Dot Files."
    $isDotFile = {$_.name -match "^\..*"}
    $isNotHidden = {$_.attributes -match 'Hidden' -eq $false}
    $dotFileCount = 0
    $markedCount = 0

    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        where $isDotFile |
        where $isNotHidden |
        foreach {
            $path = $_.FullName
            $dotFileCount++

            Write-Progress `
                -Activity $Activity `
                -Status "Found $($dotFileCount) dot files."

            if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) {
                Set-ItemProperty `
                    -name Attributes `
                    -value ([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden) `
                    -path $path

                $markedCount++
            }   
        }


    echo "Marked $($markedCount) dot file(s) as hidden."
}
```

If not given a specified path it will recursively search for all dot files in the current directory and set the attribute of the file or folder as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to make it happen automatically, but you could try using the ATTRIB command to hide those files:

ATTRIB +H

Then make sure that you've configured Explorer to not show hidden files.