# Hide Mac's ._ (dot underscore) files on a Windows share in a mixed user environment

Tags: windows, macos, windows-explorer

I work in an environment where a Macintosh user and I (a Windows user) work together. The Macintosh user generates files starting with `._` If they access a file called `foo`, they’ll create a `._foo` file in the same directory.

I'm annoyed by these files when the Macintosh user accesses a lot of files, as it makes my Explorer look very cluttered.

**How can I hide these files?**

- I can keep deleting them, but they'll just reappear. It also seems the Macintosh user notices performance differences after I've deleted them.
- I can't hide hidden files, there are hidden files which I have to access.
- I can't change any settings on the Macintosh user's system.

Is there a way for me to hide all files starting with `._`, effectively hiding the problem?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before. If you don't mind running a batch script from time to time, [this should work](http://superuser.com/a/237052/167187)

Answer (score 2):

The command below should work. Execute it after you've navigated to the directory that contains all the files (and directories) starting with `._` It will also process subdirectories and hide all folders and files that start with `._`

```
ATTRIB +H /S /D ._*
```

If you have *Show hidden files, folders, and drives* enabled, then you will still see these files. As a workaround, set the `SYSTEM` attribute in addition to the `HIDDEN` attribute with this command:

```
ATTRIB +H +S /S /D ._*
```

Hopefully, you have *Hide protected operating system files* enabled or it will not work:

[image: Hide protected operating system files]

Comment: The page you linked to appears to be a spam blog. Can you find an alternate source?

Comment: @DragonLord what page? You mean the image? Fixed it.

Comment: PCrisk.com is operated by the developer of SpyHunter, which has a record of spamming here.

Comment: @DragonLord I see. Well, I moved the image to i.stack.imgur.com so hopefully, that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you show invisible files, you'll see them.

The Mac can be told not to write them, and to be honest, I've never noticed a performance hit when doing that.

See this question: [Is there any way to prevent a Mac from creating dot underscore files?](https://superuser.com/questions/212896/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-a-mac-from-creating-dot-underscore-files)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines if setting some sort of filter, hiding files (though that would probally slow me down)